# VS 2012: Post Build xcopy error 2

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, xcopy, post-build-event

i want to make VS copy the .lib-file it created after the build process to a specific folder.
So i went to the project config, post-build event, and entered the following command:

```
if exist $(TargetPath)
xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Users\Incubbus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Libraries\z.lib" /Y
```

But instead of copying the process fails after i click "build" and i receive the following error:

> error MSB3073: The command "if exist
>   C:\Users\Incubbus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My
>   Libraries\MyNetWorkProject\Debug\IncNetworkLibD.lib xcopy
>   "C:\Users\Incubbus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My
>   Libraries\MyNetWorkProject\Debug\IncNetworkLibD.lib"
>   "C:\Users\Incubbus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Libraries\z.lib" /Y
>
> :VCEnd" exited with code 2.

I am also wondering about the `:VCEnd` in the command-string of the error message <- Maybe this is the reason? How to get this solved?

Any help and hints would be happily consumed :)...

***partial solution:***

**EDIT**: it looks like the **renaming** part (`Inc.lib` to `z.lib`) makes trouble, when xcopy asks whether this is a file or a directory...it works when i just copy the originally named file to a directory instead of copying renamed

Comment: Copy/paste the PostBuildEvent from your project file into your question.  Don't edit it, make it look exactly the same way.

Comment: it looks like the renaming part (Inc.lib to z.lib) makes trouble, when xcopy asks wether this is a file or a directory... this works when i just copy the lib-file to a directory without renaming it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4283533/532647 one possible way to resolve it. By `echo f | xcopy ...` you would just say 'file' to xcopy.

Comment: works, thx... if you post it as an answer i can mark the question as answered...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[Xcopy documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) says the following:

*Specifying whether Destination is a file or directory
If Destination does not contain an existing directory and does not end with a backslash (\), the following message appears:*

```
Does destination specify a file name 
or directory name on the target 
(F = file, D = directory)?
```

*Press F if you want the file or files to be copied to a file. Press D if you want the file or files to be copied to a directory.*

*You can suppress this message by using the /i command-line option, which causes `xcopy` to assume that the destination is a directory if the source is more than one file or a directory.*

You need the opposite, but there is no such switch.

The solution is proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4283533/532647.

It is suggested to prepend the `xcopy` command with `echo f |` prefix, which basically does the following: it simulates a user pressing `f` key when `xcopy` asks.

So your command should look like:

```
if exist $(TargetPath)
echo f | xcopy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Users\Incubbus\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\My Libraries\z.lib" /Y
```

Operator `|` just pipes the output of `echo f` (== `f`) into `xcopy` command and it is read when appropriate. More information about output redirection here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html.

**UPDATE:**
As Govert [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014763/vs-2012-post-build-xcopy-error-2#comment20331272_14022309), this hack won't work under a localized version of Windows.
However, another hack will work:

```
xcopy D:\file.zip c:\renamedFile.zip*
```

Appending destination file name with an asterisk `*` makes xcopy not ask whether destination is a file or a directory.

Comment: This does not work under localised versions of Windows, where the prompt words might be different. An alternative trick is to add an asterisk '*' to the end of the destination, then xcopy won't prompt for File/Directory.

Comment: Why does xcopy not recognize the source and/or target as a file when they have a file extension and why does the asterisk work? @Govert

Comment: @xr280xr I have not idea how xcopy works. It might be a good question to ask Raymond Chen: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing

Comment: @xr280xr Having a dot and some characters after it doesn't make a path a file. Folders can have dot in name, i.e. aaa.txt is a valid folder name.

Comment: @user3285954 Regardless, why does xcopy fail to identify a file as a file, and why does using an asterisk resolve that? (Thanks for the link, Govert)

Comment: @xr280xr There's no file yet only a path and can't decide only based on path what is the target because folder names can have "extensions" a file names may not have extensions. Copying a file to a folder is a valid operation so can't decide on source either. xcopy seems to ignore wildcards for directories probably this is why a path with wildcard is considered to be a file. To avoid confusion and hacks use copy for files.

Answer (score 12):

Why don't you use copy instead of xcopy? copy is specifically for files so there will be no confusion.

Comment: The absolutely simplest answer. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try wrapping the $(TargetPath) in quotes? The ever-so-popular-space-characters-instead-of-underscores-in-all-MS-products tend to mess things up at every corner... Dunno why those dumbos keep doing it...

Like so: if exist "$(TargetPath)"