# Getting error while copying csdef files to target directory

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, xcopy, pre-build-event

I have created multiple csdef files for different environments.
I wanted to copy correct csdef file to target directory using xcopy command in prebuild event.

> xcopy /Y "$(ProjectDir)ServiceDefinition.$(ConfigurationName).csdef"
>   "$(TargetDir)ServiceDefinition.csdef"

**I am getiing error xcopy exited with code 2.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would a post-build step (xcopy) occassionally exit with code 2 in a TeamCity build?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835304/why-would-a-post-build-step-xcopy-occassionally-exit-with-code-2-in-a-teamcity)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying environment-specific files, you could use transformations with the output going to an intermediate location.  See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844179/5382426) for details.