# Postbuild step not working in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xcopy, post-build-event

I have a VS2017 solution and I'm trying to copy an external DLL into the same folder as the final .exe executable (whether it will be Debug, Release or Publish)

tried with:

```
xcopy "$(ProjectDir)..\..\myDllFolder\myDll.dll" $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)
```

I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB3073 The command "xcopy
>   "C:\Projects\Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost\....\LMBrick\LMBrick.dll"
>   C:\Projects\Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost\bin\Release\net461\
>   /i xcopy
>   "C:\Projects\Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost\....\LMBrick\LMBrickX.dll"
>   C:\Projects\Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost\bin\Release\net461\
>   /i" exited with code
>   2.    Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost  C:\Projects\Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer\Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost\Eurotherm.Reviewer.ServiceHost.csproj    48
>
> xcopy exited with code 2

The directories are present, the input file is present. why it doesn't work? Code 2 means xcopy doesn't know if the second parameter is a folder or a file, I tried  forcing the answer using `/i` but I get the same error

Comment: Did you not want a "\" after "$(ProjectDir)" before the ".."?

Comment: Set the log mode to verbose or something so you can actually see what it is doing for the copy command.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't understand you comment. I want a ` after $(ProjectDir)` before the ... ??????

Comment: You should also wrap yours in quotes just in case you have spaces in the output path.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No spaces in the output path

Comment: I know. But it is good practice.

Comment: See if the answer here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835304/why-would-a-post-build-step-xcopy-occasionally-exit-with-code-2-in-a-teamcity