# The command exited with code 2 visual studio 2017

Tags: windows, debugging, build, msbuild, visual-studio-debugging

While I'm trying to build my windows application, I'm getting following error.

The command

> "C:\repos\CommunityLive\CL_GateApp\signing\StrongNameUnsignedAssemblies.bat
> C:\repos\CommunityLive\CL_GateApp\signing" exited with code 2.

Following is my Pre-Build event command line

```
$(ProjectDir)signing\StrongNameUnsignedAssemblies.bat $(ProjectDir)signing\
```

Here is the Macros details

[image: Macros]

Comment: An error code (also exit code) of 2 means "File not found". You would check the path in your side, and also view the bat file in your side even if we  don't know how you write it.

Comment: batch file is available at the expected location but still getting this issue.

Comment: Actually I mean that how you write your bat file, just to make this issue clearly, could you run your bat file manually in your side? If possible, you could share us a simple sample using one drive, so we could really test it in our side.

Comment: It is solved by the creator only.

Comment: @creator, Do you mean that this issue has been resolved? If so, would you please share the real solution as an answer?

Comment: I was getting this error while trying to execute `xcopy` command in post-build event. The problem was that I wasn't using `/y` argument which results in overwriting of files in target directory even if they exist already.

Comment: Related post - [Why would a post-build step (xcopy) occasionally exit with code 2 in a TeamCity build?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835304/465053)

Answer (score 0):

Xcopy command without /y can cause this:

This post-build event exited with Code 2:

```
xcopy $(TargetDir)*.*  $(SolutionDir)shared\ /s /i
```

This worked as hoped:

```
xcopy $(TargetDir)*.*  $(SolutionDir)shared\ /s /i /y
```